# How to change resolution/font size of CentOS guest VM?

Tags: linux, centos, console, resolution, distributions

I'm learning CentOS by running CentOS minimal guest on Vmware Workstation ver. 14.

The console and font seems to be too small and shows up as a small square.

How can I increase the size of this console screen and the font sizes? I'm very new to Linux so most guides I find via web search are too advanced for me and I don't know what I'm doing. Could someone show me step by step how to increase my console/font size so I can actually see what I'm typing and learn Linux?

Thanks!

Comment: this is probably more a vmware question. another option is to run the virtual machine headless and SSH into it

Comment: Are you referring to the size of the font in a graphical terminal window, or the size in a tty (basic command line interface, no graphics), or is it a question of making the window of your VM larger? Please [edit] your question and clarify.